# Sticky Footer CSS Not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked at several topics on stackoverflow and other sites, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me.

The problem is that no matter what I've tried, I still have a scrollbar added to the page that is the same height as the padding on the top of the container (wrapper) div. I can only make it work by fiddling with the min-height on the container div, which obviously wouldn't always work, and besides, is a really sloppy way to handle it. Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

(I've tried the footer inside  and outside, with the same results.)

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body > #container {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}


#content {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background: /*image here*/;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background: /*image here*/;
    height: 130px;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px #000;

    border-top: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F8F8F8;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -3em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
}
```

There may be some odd overflows in there, but they've been thrown it at different points trying to fix the problem. I use a background image that covers the entire background of the site, and a background image for the the header.

Any fiddling with the overflows, heights, margin/padding, or relative/absolute/fixed positioning have either yielded worse results, or the same results.

I'm trying to do this without JS, but if all else fails, I'm willing to resort to that. If that's the case, would anyone mind pointing me to a related JS stackoverflow question and/or a tutorial?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I've found some really good solutions that rely on 'fixed' positioning and box layout.  Don't have good code to share, because it was twitter bootstrap dependent.

Comment: This might be of some help http://jsfiddle.net/ekn9v/

Comment: Thanks, jeff! The below answer also worked, but I had to add an extra content wrapper to force it, kind of. I'll give yours a shot as well, but it looks like it should also work! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide what browser you are trying to do this in, but assuming it is a modern browser, I have found that the [cleanstickyfooter](https://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/) technique works the best. (All credit to Trevor Sheridan for this technique.) I have created an example [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBTa9/) so you can see the implementation. You can adjust the widths, etc, as you need to. The first link provides a lot of good detail.

Per SO requirements, here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <div id="content_inner_wrapper">
                <div>Site content will be contained here.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_wrapper">
        <div id="footer_inner_wrapper">
            <div>The footer's content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -41px 0px;
}
div#footer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 41px;
    background-color: red;
}
div#content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 41px 0px;
}
div#footer_wrapper, div#content_wrapper {
    min-width: 500px;
}
div#footer_inner_wrapper, div#content_inner_wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: This works really well, but with one problem. How can I have my padding at the top of the screen (a 50px gap between the top of the page and the header) and have the footer? If I have the gap added (and I've tried both margin and padding), then I have the same problem with the scrollbar.

EDIT: I was trying to get away with having only one wrapper around the content. When I added a content wrapper within my container, then added the padding to the content wrapper instead of the container, it totally worked, even when I re-size it.

Thanks!! PS - Why does this work, exactly?